# Expression.Call in simple lambda expression. Is it possible?

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, expression-trees

I need to generate a lambda expression like

```
item => item.Id > 5 && item.Name.StartsWith("Dish")
```

Ok, item.Id > 5 is simple

```
var item = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Item), "item");

var propId = Expression.Property(item,"Id");
var valueId = Expression.Constant(5);
var idMoreThanFive = Expression.GreaterThan(propId, valueId);
```

But the second part is more complex for me...

```
var propName = Expression.Property(item,"Name");
var valueName = Expression.Constant("Dish");
```

How to call StartsWith for propName?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You'll have to get a `MethodInfo` representing the `string.StartsWith(string)` method and then use [`Expression.Call`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb343914.aspx) to construct the expression representing the instancemethod call:

```
var property = Expression.Property(item, "Name");
var method = typeof(string).GetMethod("StartsWith", new[] { typeof(string) });
var argument = Expression.Constant("Dish");

// item.Name.StartsWith("Dish")
var startsWithDishExpr = Expression.Call(property, method, argument);
```

You'll then have to `&&` the subexpressions together to create the body.

```
var lambdaBody = Expression.AndAlso(idMoreThanFive, startsWithDishExpr);
```

And then finally construct the lambda:

```
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Item, bool>>(lambdaBody, item);
```

Comment: Assuming there is a class called `Item` your final line should be: `var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Item, bool>>(lambdaBody, item);`